# Possible to search Whois database by registrant name?

Tags: dns, whois, reverse-lookup

I am looking to collect domains and registrants' contact details via whois lookups.  Does anybody know of a resource that has free reverse look-ups using the registrant name as the search term?

Comment: No they got that pretty locked up. Try and scrape it for info and you will be blocked in no time. I think they are a common target for this kind of thing.

Comment: it would be a huge effort. you may go for free available service, like whoisxmlapi.com, ip2whois.com, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost (if not completely) impossible to find a free service like the one you are looking for. The reason is because it requires a huge amount of resources to perform a reverse lookup (you basically need to query as much domains as you can).

Also, keep in mind every service offering such feature can't be perfect. In fact, the only way to be perfect is to have a snapshot of every single domain registered (which is almost impossible).

Answer (score 2):

Try [WhoisFreaks](https://whoisfreaks.com/documentation/api/whois-reverse-api.html) reverse whois lookup API tool. It offers 100 free API credits. It allows you to find the reverse whois record of the domains by using the following four parameters including the registrant's name:

**1. Reverse whois with the Domain keywords:**

```
  GET https://api.whoisfreaks.com/v1.0/whois?apiKey=API_KEY&whois=reverse&keyword=youtube
```

**2. Reverse whois with the Email address:**

```
GET https://api.whoisfreaks.com/v1.0/whois?apiKey=API_KEY&whois=reverse&email=abc@gmail.com
```

**3. Reverse whois with the Registrant's name:**

```
GET https://api.whoisfreaks.com/v1.0/whois?apiKey=API_KEY&whois=reverse&owner=michal
```

**4. Reverse whois with the Company name:**

```
GET https://api.whoisfreaks.com/v1.0/whois?apiKey=API_KEY&whois=reverse&company=youtube
```